# Problema al intentar aplicar fórmula compleja en Excel

Tags: excel, formato, formulas

Información adicional: estructura de una vela japonesa

[image: Información adicional: estructura de una vela japonesa]

En este caso, el problema que tengo es debido a que la fórmula es bastante más compleja y parece que Excel no termina de reconocerla como fórmula. Al darle a aceptar, Excel me muestra un mensaje en el que dice que no está seguro de si yo trato de introducir una fórmula, o no.

Os explico: tengo una hoja Excel la cual contiene datos de velas japonesas. Cada vela se puede representar con 4 datos: 1)apertura, 2)máximo, 3)mínimo y 4)cierre.

La relación de valor y letra de la columna es la siguiente:

- (Columnas A y B son datos de fecha y hora, que no me interesan).
- Columna C -> Apertura
- Columna D -> Máximo
- Columna E -> Mínimo
- Columna F -> Cierre

La fórmula que trato de aplicar tiene 2 condiciones: la primera es que sea una **vela alcista**. Esto quiere decir que el valor de cierre(F) es superior al valor de apertura(C). Por lo que la fórmula sería:

```
=$F1>$C1
```

Posteriormente, una vez que he indicado que sólo quiero las velas alcistas, quiero que, de las velas que ahora quedan, que sólo seleccione aquellas en las que la sombra superior sea de igual o mayor longitud que el cuerpo. Por lo que (y aquí es donde tengo el problema), tengo que indicar una fórmula válida y también tengo que agregar a la fórmula que antes he puesto, esta.

Primero, describo lo que sería la **sombra superior**: Máximo - Cierre. En Excel equivale a:`$D1-$F1`

Segundo, describo lo que es el **cuerpo**: Cierre - Apertura. En Excel equivale a: `$F1-$C1`.

Por lo que, la fórmula resultante sería (en teoría, dado que me da error):
Vela Alcista Y Sombra superior => Cuerpo. En Excel equivale a:

```
=SI(Y($F1>$C1;($D1-$F1)=>($F1-$C1)))
```

Decir que dicha fórmula la introduzco en 'Formato condicional' -> 'Nueva Regla', con la finalidad de que establezca el fondo de todas las celdas de la fila donde la condición de la fórmula sea cierta, en verde.

Comment: No te faltará solamente el resultado en caso de que sea verdadero y falso? `=SI(Y(F4>C4;(D4-F4) >= (F4-C4));"si"; "no")`

Comment: He leído lo de añadir el comentario y tras probar con la fórmula que sugieres... Excel me la acepta, pero no veo que marque en color ninguna fila. Por cierto, ¿por qué usas F4 y no $F1?

Comment: Lo de los colores sería netamente por el formato condicional que le especificaste, con eso no puedo ayudarte mucho. Sólo te puedo guiar con la fórmula correcta. Lo de la celda F4 es sólo porque ingrese los datos desde esa fila, no tiene importancia :)

Comment: Cuándo uso $F1 en vez de F4, ¿se aplica a toda la selección? No entiendo el porqué del símbolo $.

Comment: El signo `$` se utiliza para fijar filas y/o columnas en una formula en particular. Si colocas $F1 estas especificando que la columna F quedara fija y sólo avanzará de fila (F1, F2, F3, etc). Consulta este enlace para más info: https://excelyvba.com/para-que-sirve-el-simbolo-en-una-formula/

Comment: podrias pasar unos datos de ejemplo y tambien aclarar si la formula funciona fuera del condicional? en general , para formulas complejas se divide la misma en columnas para ver los resultados parciales.

Comment: `=Y((F1>C1);(D1-F1)>=(F1-C1))` usandola así funciona, retorna `VERDADERO` o `FALSO`, ya con eso podrías realizar lo del color de la casilla. Pero se mantendría el texto resultante V o F.

Comment: @gbianchi te facilito el enlace del archivo completo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6LWmRqR_2aUNHBPVHRZVkdxZTg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probe con parte de los datos de tu archivo, realizando la formula así `=Y((F1>C1);(D1-F1)>=(F1-C1))` y use dos (2) formatos condicionales:

1. Para resaltar el valor a verde:
   `Formato Condicional
   -> Nueva Regla
   -> "Aplicar formato únicamente a las celdas que contengan"
   [Texto específico] - [que contiene] - ["VERDADERO"]`

   - Para el formato de color al texto le coloque el mismo color `Verde` que el que le coloque a la celda *esto es para que no se vea el texto*

[image: captura de pantalla caso VERDADERO]

2. Para colocar las letras de `FALSO` de color blanco y no se vea el texto:
   `Formato Condicional
   -> Nueva Regla
   -> "Aplicar formato únicamente a las celdas que contengan"
   [Texto específico] - [que contiene] - ["FALSO"]`

   - Para el formato de color al texto le coloque el color `Blanco`

[image: captura de pantalla caso FALSO]

> Se aplica en una celda seleccionada (en mi caso la función
>   `=Y((F1>C1);(D1-F1)>=(F1-C1))`) esta en la celda `H` y tome como
>   ejemplo la celda `H1` luego se replica para las demás celdas.

[Ejemplo usado (GDrive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1lwu-xNDTDSSmR4bjI1WkxyX00)

Comment: Perfecto Cesar Romero. Ahora parece que funciona a la perfección. Eso sí, la fórmula la tengo que retocarla más dado que necesito que sea aún más precisa, pero cumple con las expectativas sobradamente y tu explicación es fenomenal. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una pregunta... Si quisiera añadir más condiciones (tengo entendido que Excel admite hasta 64 condiciones), ¿tendría que usar el punto y coma para introducir la siguiente condición? `Y((F1>C1);CONDICIÓN 2; CONDICIÓN 3)`

Comment: Saludos @RichardSteele, si es correcto si deseas agregar mas condiciones basta con agegarlas con el `;` para separar cada condición. Que bueno haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Cesar-Romero , ¡Fuíste de gran ayuda!